# How I can print an output number for a running file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

How I can get an output message which is "1" or "0" of an already running file?

I mean if i have a .jar file and i tun it by this command java -jar [FILENAME].jar, how i can output a status number( 0 if it is not running or 1 if is running)
N.B: I only want the number as an output message. In a bash script as variable.

Comment: ps, grep, echo?

Answer (score 0):

i think you are expecting something like this,

```
[ $(ps -ef | grep "[FILENAME].jar" | grep -v "grep" | wc -l) -gt 0 ] && echo "1" || echo "0"
```

if need bit more detailed version, then below will suit i guess,

```
if [ $(ps -ef | grep "[FILENAME].jar" | grep -v "grep" | wc -l) -gt 0 ];then
   echo "1"
else
   echo "0"
fi
```

Comment: no i want to have this in a variable
i take your example
status=$(ps -ef | grep "[FILENAME],jar" | grep -v "grep" | wc -l) -gt 9)

and if i want to output this message like this
echo "${status}"
if echo he says only "0" or "1".

Comment: @Leutech , instead of `echo "1"` and `echo "0"` , if we are assigning a variable `i` there , will it do your work ? that is if we change like this, `echo "1" change to i=1` and `echo "0" change to i=0`